# Error when trying to store a file name into a variable (cmd)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles, dism

Basically I wanna find a .wim file and want to know in which volume it is and what the name is.

This is my code:

```
@for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do @if exist %%a:\*.wim set IMAGEDRIVE=%%a
@echo The Image drive is: %IMAGEDRIVE%
@forfiles /P %IMAGEDRIVE%:\ /S /C "cmd /c set FILENAME=@FNAME"
@echo The File name is: %FILENAME%
@pause
```

Because i later wanna do this:

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:%IMAGEDRIVE%:\%FILENAME%.wim /applydir:w:\ /Index:1
```

It correctly finds the Volume H where the image.wim file is.
But it cant find anything when trying to get the name.
The File is there I checked that already.

What am i doing wrong?
Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You don't need to use `FORFILES` to get a filename.  A basic `FOR` command will iterate the files in a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `cmd /c set FILENAME=@FNAME"` executes the `set` command in a separate process that immediately exits and destroys the variable (it's only available in the child process opened by `cmd /c` but not in the calling parent process (where you need it).

I would replace the `forfiles` command with another `for` loop:

```
for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do for %%b in ("%%a:\*.wim") do set "imagefile=%%b"
echo the File name is: %imagefile%
```